# How to use IN query for WMI execution

Tags: c#, wmi

Below WMI query gives me invalid query syntax error, How to use IN operator?

```
select DriverVersion,Description from Win32_PnPSignedDriver WHERE Description in ('Dell Touchpad', 'WiFi')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use WQL for querying WMI ..  [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/wql-sql-for-wmi)

```
select DriverVersion,Description from Win32_PnPSignedDriver WHERE (Description='Dell Touchpad') or  (Description='WiFi')
```

Answer (score 1):

WMI uses WQL which is a very basic subset of SQL query language so you would likely not be able to use IN clause. There are quiete a bit of restrictions to WQL. You have the definition right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi

You can also use ORMi which will help you to work with WMI without having to write WQL queries. You can just do:

```
var devices = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver")
                    .Where(p => p.Description == "Dell Touchpad" || p.Description == "WiFi");
```